# send # in URL without encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularjs where I am constructing a POST url(This URL is outside of my application) by appending the parameters that external application expects.
The parameters that I send contains '#' in it. My value is  XXX1011#32.

The browser trims the # and the content after that and sent it as XXX1011, which is not a valid number. How do tell browser to ignore this #.

I cannot use encodeURIComponent because, the value is not decoded on the external application and I don't have control on it.

If I have to send multiple values like  XXX1011#32, PPP1011#29 , how do I send.

$.post( postUrl, function ( data )
                {
                    var new_window = window.open( theHost + '/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet?', 'windowname' );
                    new_window.document.write( data );
                    new_window.document.close();
                } );

postUrl = theHost + '/externalApp/OutputServlet?' + inputVals + $scope.seriesIdArr;

$scope.seriesIdArr is where I have to send values.

Comment: you... don't have a choice. you must encode, or it *will* be lost.

Comment: because # is a hash.... and that is not sent to the server... so you need to encode.

Comment: If you can change the backend to accept JSON, you could then avoid encoding it. but if you can't even modify the server to properly decode values, you likely can't make it accept json either..

Comment: Or just use post body to send your data.

Comment: I think using POST body is the only way. I was trying that but some how somewhere something is wrong.  The external application get the parameters like, request.getParameterValues("ID");.

Comment: I think using POST body is the only way. I was trying that but some how somewhere something is wrong.  @Nicolas,  The external application expects a string array, like ID=[ ' XXX1011#32',  'PPP1011#29']. My code is sending as   XXX1011#32,'PPP1011#29